# reference a range that is in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I know this answer is out there, I am just not using the write words to ask.

In cell B1 I have `"Form Responses 1'!$C:$C"` written out.

In cell B3 I have a countif formula that I would like to use the contents of cell B1 as the range.   So something like the below

`=COUNTIF(B1,"Option 1")`, or I have tried `=COUNTIF(Indirect(B1),"Option 1")`

Both don't see the the contents of B1 as a range, and therefore it is not giving me a count of the items in the range.

Comment: do you have in cell B1 with double quotes or without double quotes (ie., `"Form Responses 1'!$C:$C"` or `Form Responses 1'!$C:$C`)? also do you have have single quote after 1? I tried with `Form Responses 1!$C:$C` in my sheet. It works

Comment: 'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C  and I have tried "'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C", I get 0 if I use the cell reference to B1, and 2 if I put the range in manually.

Comment: Dont single quote or double quote then it works.

Comment: I have Form Responses 1!$C:$C this is working fine with indirect

Comment: It was the single quote before Form and after the 1 that was making it not work for me.   Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without B cells:

```
=COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!C:C,"Option 1")
```

Comment: It works without the cell reference, but I am writing a script that will be creating many identical sheets and I would like to just change cell B1 and have the rest just work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Abdul Hameed, I came up with two solutions.

Cell B1 = "C"
my countif formula is: =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!$"&B1&":$"&B1),"Option 1")

or to directly answer my first question
Cell B1 = Form Responses 1!$C:$C   (no double or single quotes)
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(B1),"Option 1")